# Can anyone help me with date command

Tags: mysql, date

So I´ve looked trough the web in search for basic date help in sql and nobody seems to be able to help my codes goes like this

```
create table Hotel
(
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Name varchar(255)
);

create table Gestur
(
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    nafn varchar(255),
    heimili varchar(255),
    simi char(7),
    netfang varchar(255)
);

create table Bokun
(
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    ID_hotel_fk int references Hotel(id),
    ID_gestur_fk int references Gestur(id),
    dags_inn date null,
    dags_ut date null,
    tegund_herbergis char(1)
);
```

and I can´t seem to get this part right

```
insert into Bokun
(ID_gestur_fk,ID_hotel_fk,dags_inn,dags_ut,tegund_herbergis)
values
(1,3, 2015-10-25,2016-12-26,"1"),
(2,5, 2015-04-01, 2016-8-24,"3"),
(3,4, 2014-02-24, 2016-12-08,"1"),
(4,2, 2015-04-26, 2016-12-24,"2"),
(5,4, 2015-07-14, 2016-04-23,"1"),
(6,2, 2015-12-12, 2016-09-12,"3"),
(7,3, 2015-12-26, 2016-05-03,"2"),
(8,2, 2013-09-12, 2014-06-10,"1"),
(9,1, 2015-05-26, 2016-12-28,"1"),
(10,5, 2015-03-30, 2016-06-07,"4");
```

I only get the error

> 1292 - Incorrect date value: '1980' for column 'dags_inn' at row 1

Comment: Once again: **Microsoft SQL SERVER != MySQL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote dates with `'` and qoute `"1"` as `'1'`:

```
insert into Bokun(ID_gestur_fk,ID_hotel_fk,dags_inn,dags_ut,tegund_herbergis)
values(1,3, '2015-10-25','2016-12-26','1');
```

`2015-10-25` is treated as `1980` (aritmetic operation substraction)

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2693/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot you really helped me.

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into Bokun
(ID_gestur_fk,ID_hotel_fk,dags_inn,dags_ut,tegund_herbergis)
values
(1,3, '2015-10-25','2016-12-26',"1"),
(2,5, '2015-04-01', '2016-8-24',"3"),
(3,4, '2014-02-24', '2016-12-08',"1"),
(4,2, '2015-04-26', '2016-12-24',"2"),
(5,4, '2015-07-14', '2016-04-23',"1"),
(6,2, '2015-12-12', '2016-09-12',"3"),
(7,3, '2015-12-26', '2016-05-03',"2"),
(8,2, '2013-09-12', '2014-06-10',"1"),
(9,1, '2015-05-26', '2016-12-28',"1"),
(10,5, '2015-03-30', '2016-06-07',"4");
```

you missed `'`(`quotes`).Thanks this helps..